# How to change the errorElement for MVC3 unobtrusive validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, jquery-plugins

I'm working with the MVC3 unobtrusive jquery validation.  By default, the error message is put into a span which sits to the right of the validated element.  There are situations when the error message will wrap onto a next line and looks ugly.  I would like to change the "span" to a "div" so that the error element will display on its own line.  I would also like to know, in general, how to override the jQuery defaults for the validator *without* modifying the jQuery libraries.

I have tried both of these javascript calls to trigger validation.  This one doesn't validate:

```
var settngs = $.validator.defaults;
settngs.errorElement = "div";
$('#createForm').validate();
```

...and this one doesn't set the errorElement:

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('#createForm'));
```

I haven't been able to figure this out just by looking at the js files. Surely I'm missing something.

Answer (score -1):

on line 108 (at least the version I have) of `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` I found:

```
errorElement: "span",
```

just change this to:

```
errorElement: "div",
```

this created a div below my field rather then a span beside it

Comment: Thanks, but as I said, I don't want to change either of the jQuery validation files.

Comment: oops! missed that part sorry.